# How to get the status of child Jenkins Job from parent Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am currently running 2 Jenkins jobs where one Jenkins Job (Job A) calling another Jenkins Job (Job B) by using "when builds promote". Once it is approved manually, then Job B job will get triggered. After this step, I need the scenario like I would like to get status from Job B in Job A.

If my Job B fails then Job A should fail or vice versa. Any help!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fundamentals of how Jenkins works. If an upstream job (job 1) is successful and the downstream job (job 2) fails, Jenkins is doing its job correctly by showing the actual statuses of the jobs (i.e., job 1 is green and job 2 is red).

If the upstream job fails then the downstream should never kick off in the first place, so you won't have to worry about that. This is how Jenkins was designed to work.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I got your point. but is there any way where i can write a script (jenkins job status script for job 2) in post build actions of job 1 and sleep for sometime until job 2 gets executed and give the status back to parent job 1?